# Bluetooth Low Energy scanning no results on Samsung S8

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, samsung-mobile

I'm developing an application with Bluetooth Low Energy. Currently, I am using Samsung S8 as test phone, and BLE scanning not working(No scan results).

Some notes:

1. App is targeting to API 18, so there is no need to request location permissions at runtime
2. During scan, location is always enabled.
3. Other devices (Xiaomi, Android 6) are working well and BLE scanner sees nearby devices.
4. BLE devices are visible during scan in phone's settings.

Also I always see such logs during scan:

```
 E/BluetoothServiceJni: An exception was thrown by callback 'btgattc_scan_result_cb'.
 E/BluetoothServiceJni: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
                                                              at android.bluetooth.le.ScanRecord.isMultiManudata(ScanRecord.java:321)
                                                              at android.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter.matches(ScanFilter.java:316)
                                                              at com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService.matchesFilters(GattService.java:907)
                                                              at com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService.onScanResult(GattService.java:842)
```

I searched a lot and can't can't find any information about my situation, there are similar questions, but location enabling is the solution for all of them.

Comment: Your `ArrayList` appears to be `null`... I'd investigate that.

Comment: @DigitalNinja look closely, this is not my arrays, this is an internal crash

Comment: Oh, it's not? Then yeah, totally just ignore the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @DigitalNinja am ignoring this exception, but I totally not understanding why the hell it is not working on Samsung S8

Comment: You should send a bug report to Samsung because it's their code that crashes.